# how to put a condition for all combinations of 2 of a set variables equaling each other

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements, combinations

```
spades = ['2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','10S','JS','QS','KS','AS']
hearts = ['2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','10H','JH','QH','KH','AH']
clubs = ['2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','10C','JC','QC','KC','AC']
diamonds = ['2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','10D','JD','QD','KD','AD']

suits = [spades,hearts,clubs,diamonds]


randomD = int(random.random()*4)
random4 = int(random.random()*(len(suits[randomD])-1))
CPcard1 = suits[randomD][random4]
del suits[randomD][random4]

for suit in suits:
    if CPcard1 in suit:
        CPcard1i = suit.index(CPcard1)
    if CPcard2 in suit:
        CPcard2i = suit.index(CPcard2)
    if card1 in suit:
        card1i = suit.index(card1)
    if card2 in suit:
        card2i = suit.index(card2)
    if card3 in suit:
        card3i = suit.index(card3)
```

I want to make a condition for when 2 of these variables are identical without doing...

```
if CPcard1 == CPcard2 or CPcard1 == card1 or CPcard1  == card2 (etc)
```

This is part of a poker simulation I'm making.(note: CPcard1 and CPcard2 belong to the first player and cards 1,2 and 3 belong tothe table. all cards where found with the same method as CPcard1 above) I just want to make the program identify a pair. I'm relatively new to coding and I'm a noob so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Put them in a `set` and check the size? BTW, do you know about `random.randint` and `random.choice`? Also, you do not pick cards randomly. Even after you picked 9 cards from hearts, the chance to get another heart will be 1/4.

Comment: `'CPcard2' is not defined` CPcard2 is missing. Could you update your code according to its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some notes about your setup: The way you select random cards is (a) cumbersome, and (b) incorrect. By randomly selecting a suit, and then a card from that suit, each suit has the same chance of being selected (1/4), even if there is just one (or none!) card left in that suit.

Instead, I suggest just doing it the same way you would do in real life: Put all the cards in one deck, [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the deck, and pop cards from that shuffled deck.

```
all_cards = spades + hearts + clubs + diamonds
random.shuffle(all_cards)
hand = [all_cards.pop() for _ in range(5)]
```

Also, instead of manually enumerating all the cards, you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
values = list('23456789') + ['10'] + list('JQKA')
suits = list('SHCD')
all_cards = [''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(suits, values)]
```

---

About finding pairs (or triplets, or quadruplets): The easiest way to do this would be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). But also note that you do not really need the cards to be the same, as you do with `==`! Instead, it is enough if the value is the same, the suit can be different.

```
import collections
counts = collections.Counter([card[:-1] for card in hand])
```

Here, `card[:-1]` will get the value from the card string, e.g. `'10'` from `'10S'`. You can then use `counts.most_common` to get the most common pairs (or triplets, etc.), if any.

Example:

```
>>> hand
['3C', '6S', 'KC', 'JH', 'KH']
>>> counts
Counter({'K': 2, '3': 1, 'J': 1, '6': 1})
```